# ccache make recompiling whole program again and again

Tags: linux, ubuntu, make, build

I have two projects on Linux mint 16,  I switch between. I am using ccache make so that i can compile only changes in the program but It is recompiling from scratch. build system is cmake. 
If I compile one project and then switch to another and compile it, After this ccache should recompile only changes as make will do as if I was working with only one project. But it recompiles from the scratch.

How to handle multiple projects with ccache? Is ccache really caching?

Comment: It is common to have a tag file which is a dependency of everything in a make file, so that touching it forces a complete rebuild, often with a name like **rebuild.all**. Maybe your make files have a common rebuild tag file name.

Comment: So, I should remove that phony target?

Comment: No, just change its name throughout the makefile on one of the projects.